# Consulta en desorden PosgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

¿Cómo podría hacer una consulta SQL insertando una cadena con palabras en cualquier orden?
Por ejemplo encontrar una fila que tenga en alguna columna el siguiente String:
"mi perro se llama spike" insertando en un like algo como "perro mi llama se spike"

Veamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
create table demo(
  texto varchar(255)
);

insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llama spike');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llamarada spike');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro dinamita');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llama spike y mi gato felix');
insert into demo(texto) values ('perro mi llama se spike');
```

La idea sería: poder buscar una serie de palabras (todas deberían aparecer), dentro de la columna texto, de tal forma que si buscáramos `perro mi llama se spike`, el resultado debería ser:

```
texto
--------------------------------------
mi perro se llama spike
perro mi llama se spike
mi perro se llama spike y mi gato felix
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: podrias aclarar que base de datos estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando PostgreSQL

Comment: Entonces por favor, aclaralo con un tag en la pregunta. tambien mira los links que te pase. Deberias decir que cosas probaste y no funcionaron.

Comment: No veo los links.

Comment: los links de [ask] <-este y [tour] <- este

Comment: Que es lo que buscas? las filas que contengan todas las palabras que indicaste sin importar el orden?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Las filas que cierta columna contenga todas las palabras que indiqué sin importar el orden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco en profundidad PostgreSql, así que tuve que investigar un poco. Conceptualmente el problema es que tenemos una lista de palabras y queremos encontrar todas estas en una determinada columna de una tabla, todas sin importar el orden. Primero armamos un pequeño ejemplo:

```
create table demo(
  texto varchar(255)
);

insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llama spike');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llamarada spike');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro dinamita');
insert into demo(texto) values ('mi perro se llama spike y mi gato felix');
insert into demo(texto) values ('perro mi llama se spike');
```

#### Expandiendo las palabras a buscar en una tabla

```
select texto       
       from demo d
       left join unnest(regexp_split_to_array('perro mi llama se spike', '\s')) p
            on position(' ' || p.p || ' ' in ' ' || d.texto || ' ') > 0
       group by d.texto
       having count(1) >= array_length(regexp_split_to_array('perro mi llama se spike', '\s'),1)
;
```

Con `regexp_split_to_array()` y el patrón `\s` (cualquier espacio en blanco) hacemos un split de la frase a buscar y generamos un array, el cual mediante `unnest()` transformamos en una tabla, ésta la usamos en un `left join` con la tabla dónde buscaremos las ocurrencias, la idea es devolver los casos dónde coincida cada palabra y por último hacemos un `group by` trayendo aquellos casos dónde la cantidad de coincidencias es igual a la cantidad de palabras a buscar.

**Nota 1**: para evitar falsos positivos, por ejemplo que `llama` coincida con `llamarada`, agregamos espacios a derecha e izquierda de la columna a buscar y verificamos siempre las palabras con espacios: `position(' ' || p.p || ' ' in ' ' || d.texto || ' ') > 0`

**Nota 2**: si no nos importan mayúsculas y minúsculas, podemos normalizar ambas cadenas, por ejemplo: `position(' ' || lower(p.p) || ' ' in ' ' || lower(d.texto) || ' ') > 0`

Comment: @IrvinLara, ahí edité la respuesta para unificar mayúsculas y minúsculas en caso que lo necesites así.

Comment: Al parecer el cambio no se reflejó.

Comment: @IrvinLara, es cierto ahí volví a editar. También modifique tu pregunta para que sea más precisa y acorde a las normas de SOes, cualquier cosa me dices. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!